# BigDecimal.divide(BD,int,RM) - BigDecimal cannot be converted to double error

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal, divide, incompatibletypeerror

The situation:

```java
  public static double pi(int a) {
    return (BigDecimal.valueOf(53360*sqrt(640320))).divide(computeS(a),a,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
  }
```

with: `private static BigDecimal computeS(int a)`

[image: and here is the terminal]

The problem is that while I compile the program it make a incompatible types error telling me that "`BigDecimal cannot be converted to double`" which seem to be a nonsense when you know that `BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal,int,RoundingMode)` doesn't need any double and his polymorphic methods neither...

So I'm a bit stuck here. Can anyone help? Thanks!

PS: I also tried to put a double instead of a BigDecimal but as expected:
[image: terminal]

Comment: Have you tried `return BigDecimal.valueOf(53360 * sqrt(640320)).divide(computeS(a), a, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();` - i.e. add `.doubleValue()` to the expression.

Comment: Ahno ok ^^' I didn't catch that the espected return value was set to double!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the `divide` method, the problem is that your `pi` method must return a `double`, but you are returning a `BigDecimal` .

Return the `double` you get by calling [doubleValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()) on it .

```
return (BigDecimal.valueOf(53360*sqrt(640320))).divide(computeS(a),a,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();
```

Comment: yep ty! I dont know why I didn't catch that the espected return value was set to double^^'